# How to put space at a new line html5?

Tags: css, html

I want to make something like on this site (http://omotesundo.com/). Please watch the "ACCESS" section. How can I make the same table with contact information? I'm trying to make it with `<ul></ul>` element, but it differs from the table on that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple example:

html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Phone<i>:</i></span>
        <p>1212</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>Adress<i>:</i></span>
        <p>here herehere here<br> here</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul{list-style:none;}
ul li span{display:block; width:60px; float:left;}
ul li span i{float:right; font-style: normal;}
ul li p{margin-left:63px;}
```

result http://jsfiddle.net/vpnypteL/

Answer (score 0):

the contact information is an image. For spacing in line you can use `&nbsp;` or you can use  `<pre>Text here</pre>` to display text as how you write